# Radiallahu anha or Alahi wasllam for Mariam?

Tags: adab, maryam, honorifics

Which is the correct islamic honorific to use after Mariam(Mother of Eeasaa [A.W])?

- رضي الله عنه (Radi Allahu 'anha)

or

- عليه والسلام (Alahi wasllam)

Same question for Asiya, wife of the Fir-aun.

Both these ladies' names are mentioned in Al-Quran.

I need to know the Islamic honorific for these two and What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 5):

First as Mariam is a female name you should consider to use the feminine form:

> رضي الله عنها (Radia Allahu 'anha)

or

> عليها السلام ('alayha as-Salam)

Then radia Allahu 'anha or 'anhu (or rahimahu Allah) could be said about anybody you want to which them well, sahaba, tabi'yn, scholars, teachers, parents ... (see this [Fatwa in Arabic](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=10967))

And 'alayha as-Salam or the masculin form are usually used for prophets as... (See the following [Fatwa](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=38427) in Arabic).

But be aware all these sentences or expressions are more a kind of dua' then a honorific title.

In the case of Mariam bint 'imran (مريم ابنة عمران) i found this [Fatwa](http://islamqa.info/en/178240) in which the scholar used the expression رضي الله عنها (Radia Allah 'anha, May Allah be pleased with her) instead of 'Allayha as-Salam when speaking about her! But on the other hand [ibn Kathir](https://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=1099&idto=1099&bk_no=49&ID=1120) and [al-Qurtubi](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=48&surano=19&ayano=1), say Mariam (عليها السلام) in their tafsir. In tafsir ibn Kathir you may read for example:

> تفسير سورة مريم عليها السلام وهي مكية
>   Tafsir of the surah of Mariam peace be upon her which was revealed in Mekkah

While a Hadith quoted in Musnad al Imam Ahmad narrated by ibn 'Abbas (MAy Allah be pleased with both of them) our Messenger (Peace be upon him) himself honored his wife Khadija, his daughter Fatima and Aasiya bint Muzajim (the wife of Pharao) and Mariam bint 'Imran by saying Radia Allahu 'anhun and counting them among the best woman in Janah:

> خَطَّ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ فِي الْأَرْضِ
>   أَرْبَعَةَ خُطُوطٍ ، قَالَ : تَدْرُونَ مَا هَذَا ؟ فَقَالُوا : اللَّهُ
>   وَرَسُولُهُ أَعْلَمُ . فَقَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ
>   وَسَلَّمَ : أَفْضَلُ نِسَاءِ أَهْلِ الْجَنَّةِ : خَدِيجَةُ بِنْتُ
>   خُوَيْلِدٍ ، وَفَاطِمَةُ بِنْتُ مُحَمَّدٍ ، وَآسِيَةُ بِنْتُ مُزَاحِمٍ
>   امْرَأَةُ فِرْعَوْنَ ، وَمَرْيَمُ ابْنَةُ عِمْرَانَ **رَضِيَ اللَّهُ
>   عَنْهُنَّ أَجْمَعِينَ**

Which could be supported by [this hadith](http://sunnah.com/urn/737660) from Jami' at-Tirmidhi but this narration is without any honorific expression!

So there's no clear consensus about this as it seems, but the expression May Allah be pleased with her  would be at least convenient in any case!

And Allah knows best!

Answer (score 3):

At this time, I cannot give the source but, in my Country, Indonesia,

**Messengers and Angels** get title **Alaihi sallam** (AS.), 
Except **Rasulullah Muhammad** who get **Sallallahu Alaihi Wasallam** (SAW.)

then
**The Companions and around** them get **Radhiallahu anhu** (RA.).

Answer (score 1):

السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته

I'm from Medina (City of the Prophet Mohammad peace be upon him), I learned at school that the correct Islamic honorific to use after Mariam (Mother of Eeasaa [Alayhi As-sllam])
Is ***Alayha As-salam*** *(**عليها السلام**)* but there is no problem if you used ***Radi Allahu 'anha*** (رضي الله عنها) both of them have close meaning.

If you need source (in Arabic): [http://articles.islamweb.net](http://articles.islamweb.net/media/index.php?page=article&id=175527)

Answer (score -2):

Radhiallahu anhu goes for the Anbia (all male prophets), but Sallallahu Alaihi Wasallam is always said for Nabi Muhammad (S.A.W.) only.

And Messengers ie. Hazrat Moosa(A.I) gets Alaihi wasallam

Radiallahu anha goes for females.

Comment: *Radhiallahu anhu goes for the Anbia*, I think it's wrong

Comment: I think so.. never heard like that before

Comment: Radhiallaahu anhu goes for Sabaye keram.

Comment: The post has mixed truths & falsehood, anyone who reads it should be aware so that may not be misguided inshAllah